# How to convert list of JSON strings to Java Objects

Tags: java, json

I have troubles with converting elements from JSON file into objects in Java. I tried some ways, but I have a specific JSON file that is hard for me to succeed.

Here is part of JSON file called "movies.json":

```
[...,

 {"title":"Dirty Grandpa",
 "year":2016,
 "director":"Dan Mazer",
 "cast":"Zac Efron, Robert De Niro, Zoey Deutch, Aubrey Plaza",
 "genre":"Comedy",
 "notes":"Lions Gate Entertainment"},

 {"title":"The Jungle Book",
  "year":2016,
  "director":"Jon Favreau",
  "cast":"Bill Murray, Ben Kingsley, Idris Elba",
  "genre":"Adventure",
  "notes":"Walt Disney Pictures, Based on the story of the same name by Rudyard Kipling"},

 {"title":"Geostorm",
  "year":2016,
  "director":"Dean Devlin",
  "cast":"Gerard Butler, Andy Garcia, Ed Harris, Katheryn Winnick",
  "genre":"Action",
  "notes":"Warner Bros."}]
```

I have to load this file and for every movie in this list I have to create the movie Object which will contain an ArrayList actors.

So the value for "key" as "cast" will be actors. They are the String separated by ",". I have to make every actor an Object Actor and collect them in the ArrayList actors in given Movie object.

How to do that?

I tried to implement the Movie class:

```
public class Movie {

@JsonProperty("title")
public String title;

@JsonProperty("year")
public Integer year;

@JsonProperty("director")
public String director;

@JsonProperty("cast")
public ArrayList<Actor> actors; }
```

But I don't know how to deal with the Actor class, since the actors can't be read as a @JsonProperty().

I should probably use the jackson ObjectMapper and the method readValue(), but it seems to be too complicated for me right now.

Could someone help me how to deal with this?

Comment: add the name of your json array.

Comment: The json file is called "movies.json" if I understood you right. It starts with "[" and ends with "]".

Comment: https://github.com/huyvanvo94/WeatherApp-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/huyvo/cmpe277/sjsu/weatherapp/util/JsonHelper.java

Comment: looks like you are new to JSON? If so just use my link I wrote a while back

Comment: Yes I am new to JSON. What should I look for in your code?

Comment: My link is a helper class for json conversion. Is this in Android or Spring?

Comment: I see. I am neither using Spring Framework nor Android. I am using maven for this project and this is the exercise for training I am doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website to produce your pojo from json.

[Json2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

This website offers many many other features and translate options for Json and JsonSchemas, and much much more.

After that your can just use the Mapper of faster.jackson package to parse json or translate it to object again.